# Correlation with trilogy of movies in Discworld timeline?

Tags: discworld

I was reading the timeline of "Discworld" on [L-space](https://www.lspace.org/books/timeline/dw-timeline.html), and I noticed this at the bottom of the page.

> Anyone note the years and their correlation with a certain trilogy of movies?

Which trilogy are they referring to?

Answer (score 7):

last note of the timeline :

> 2015  Librarian travels back in time through lspace to 1985 to rescue
>   books from Great Fire of Ephebe.

Those years, added to the mention of time travel makes me think automatically to 'back to the future'. Especially [back to the future 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096874/).
'Back to the future' that happens to be a trilogy.

I have no source to back me up on this.

Comment: could well be marty travels forward 30 years to 2015 - librarian travels back 30 years to 1985